# Accessing Setup Log for Longer than 180 Days/20 Entires

Tags: logging

We have a requirement to have record setup activities for much longer that 180 days/20 Entries limitations.

We were thinking of copying the log to another object either in SF or outside a few times a day or even every hour.

Is there a way to programmatically do that?

If there's no API for then perhaps screen-scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such developed component in Salesforce for tracking activities more than 180 days/20 Entries.

You may go for setting up one of these options:

- Create a custom object and schedule your recent records using Apex
  Batches -  but that may eat your Salesforce storage limits very soon.
- I should recommend setting up a local / remote database of any type
  (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres etc) and sync with Salesforce using data
  loader tool (if the structure is not involving deep relationships)
  otherwise you may need to use some ETL tools like Informatica, Boomi 
  etc.
- If your data seems complex and requires some manipulations as    well
  then I would recommend writing an external application (Java,
  Node.js, .Net etc) and host them locally/remotely (like Heroku).

Let me know if it doesn't suffice your requirements.

Comment: Sounds plausible. But I fail to understand how to access the recent records using Apex Batches.    

Is the idea to access the object holding those log entries and write them elsewhere?   That's where we are going, but had not thought of Apex batches, What object holds that info?

Comment: If we execute the nightly batch, we may go for checking the Lastmodified date field coming in the bracket. We may get those records and place them in a new object via Batch. And here we require a replica of the object (as a custom object) we're actually wanna copy from.